# Defining Datagrid structure programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have used a nested datagrid in my code and following is its definition. 
Iam pretty much confused on how do I define this same structure programmatically instead of xaml.

```
<DataGrid
        x:Name="objDatagrid"
        ItemsSource="{Binding DataView}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            >
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick" Handler="rowdoubleclick"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                        <DataGrid
            x:Name="objInnerDatagrid"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=objDatagrid, Path=SelectedItem.inner_object}"> 
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col1" Width="SizeToHeader" Binding="{Binding Col1}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col2" Width="80" Binding="{Binding Col2}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col3" Width="80" Binding="{Binding Col3}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col4" Width="120" Binding="{Binding Col4}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col5" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Col5}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Kindly help me to define this datagrid programmatically(i.e create this datagrid and its binding programmatically)

Comment: Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for.

Comment: Has @HighCore says, there shouldn't be a need to procedurally generate WPF UI Elements. Defining the element procedurally will pretty much break the MVVM pattern that is recommended for WPF.

Comment: I should explain first what made me create this structure programmatically . I have a tab control and in .xaml.cs code I create a customcontrol and add this thing to tab control as a child rent.  My custom control has no elements just a simple grid. Whenever my window is loaded, I create a datagrid(can be anything simple datagrid as well nested) programmatically and add it to grid. The reason behind doing this is that nested datagrid can be of various levels (2 in our example).